# TypeConverter DateTime Format issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, type-conversion

I am using 4.0 and I am trying to make my life easy by developing some helper methods for type conversions. Following method is working perfectly. It will convert from any string to other datatype.

```
System.ComponentModel;

public static T Convert<T>(string s)
{
      var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
      if (typeConverter != null && typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
      {
          return (T)typeConverter.ConvertFrom(s);
      }
      return default(T);
}

//calling this method...
var dateTime = MyConverter.Convert<DateTime>("13/07/2013");   // Date format "DD/mm/yyyy" 
// Working as expected... Taking "13" as Day, "07" as month
```

Now the following method is also in the same class MyConverter but it is not working well with DateTime:

```
public static bool CanConvertTo<T>(string s)
{
     var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));

     if (typeConverter != null && typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
     {
         return typeConverter.IsValid(s);
     }
     else
         return false;
}
```

The problem with this method is, it is only accepting dateformat : "MM/dd/yyyy"

```
// This will give exception. It is taking "13" as month, "07" as Day
bool canConvert = MyConverter.CanConvertTo<DateTime>("13/07/2013");
```

**EDIT**
As suggested by KeyboardP, I changed my method to :

```
public static bool CanConvertTo<T>(string s)
{
    TypeConverter typeConverter;
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
    {
         typeConverter = new DateTimeConverter();
    }
    else
    {
        typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    }

    if (typeConverter != null && typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
    {
        return typeConverter.IsValid(s);
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

and tested. Test results are :

```
var date = MyConverter.Convert<DateTime>("13/07/2013");    //return perfect date
var canConvert = MyConverter.CanConvertTo<DateTime>("13/07/2013");  // returned false...
```

So no success with `DateTimeConverter`

Comment: Sounds like a cultural difference between US and european dates. Try 13/13/2013 and see if that breaks it.

Comment: If it is cultural difference then why one method is working and other not?

Comment: Well what happens if you passed in a value with a more explicit date format - '13 Jun 2013'? I'd imagine that will work with both methods.

Comment: `GetCoverter(typeof(DateTime))` will return a `DateTimeConverter` so that check is unnecessary. I was saying that optional parameters need to be taken in if you want to specify the format. However, your question of why `IsValid` returning false, yet parsing is true is a good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `DateTime` can have many different format styles I'd just use [DateTimeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.datetimeconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) than attempt to recreate it inside a generic method.

**Edit**

I did a bit of ILspying and this is what I've concluded (happy to be corrected on any point).

`GetCoverter(typeof(DateTime))` will return a `DateTimeConverter` so calling `CanConvertFrom` is actually calling `DateTimeConverter.CanConvertFrom`. `CanConvertFrom` calls `base.CanConvertFrom` (`base` being the parent TypeConverter class).

The **base.CanConvertFrom** method looks like this

```
public virtual bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
{
    return sourceType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor);
}
```

Since `DateTime.GetType() != typeof(InstanceDescriptor)`, the return value is `false`. `CanConvertFrom` is called by the `IsValid` method and since we've just established the return value is `false`, `IsValid` returns `false`.

So how comes the `Convert` method works even though the same `CanConvertFrom` method is called?

Well, the parameter you're passing is of type `string`, not `DateTime`.

```
typeConverter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string))
```

In the first code snippet above, the `CanConvertFrom` method is for the `TypeConverter` base class. If we look at `DateTimeConverter.CanConvertFrom` override, it looks like this

```
public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
{
    return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
}
```

Since we're passing in a `String` as the type, this method returns true (unlike the `IsValid` call). Because this returns true, the code continues to call

```
return (T)typeConverter.ConvertFrom(s);
```

(where T is a `DateTime`)

The `DateTimeConverter` simply calls `DateTime.Parse` and ignores culture. I'm not sure whether this is by design or a bug but I wouldn't rely on `DateTime.Parse` unless you know the string is always of the same format (or you format it correctly before calling your method).

Comment: Well I am trying to develop something which can be used for all datatypes including datetime. DateTimeConverter is only for the datetime.

Comment: I understand but because `DateTime` has quite a lot more complexity than the other formats you're trying to convert to and from, you're just reinventing the wheel. If you really want to do it then your method could check if `T` is a `DateTime` object and just call `DateTimeConverter` yourself. Either way, your method will have to start to accept optional parameters so that you can specify the `DateTime` string format.

Comment: I am following what you are saying but it's not just about solving the problem. On same machine, same cultural configurations, same class 'TypeDescriptor', same date '13/07/2013', one method is working and one is not. That's a bug in my eyes.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's not a direct answer as to how to fix it but I think it explains why you're getting two different results.

Comment: Oh that's lot of information. Thanks you very much for all the effort :)

Comment: You're welcome, it was an interesting question! If there's something unclear in the explanation, feel free to ask and I'll try and clarify :)

Answer (score 0):

DateTimeConverter.IsValid doesn't use current culture. Here's how I got around this

```
public class FixedDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverter
{
    public override bool IsValid(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value)
    {
        DateTime d;
        return DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out d);
    }
}
```

...

```
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof (T));

if (typeof (T) == typeof (DateTime))
    converter = new FixedDateTimeConverter(); 

return converter.IsValid(null,r);
```